# cannot convert ‘WonderT’ to ‘WonderT*’ for argument ‘1’

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm new to this site, but I wasn't able to find a solution on here that solved my problem. I'm trying to make part of a game with my friend, and I was wondering if anyone could help steer us in the right direction. We get this error message when we try to compile "cannot convert ‘WonderT’ to ‘WonderT*’ for argument ‘1’". If someone could help I'd really appreciate.

```
void WonderSelect(Player&, int, WonderT[]);

WonderT wonders[MAX_WONDER_COUNT];
Player player1, player2;


void WonderSelect(Player& players, int wonderCount, WonderT wonders[]) {
  players.SetPick(rand() % wonderCount);
  PrintWonders(wonders[players.GetPick()]);
  return;
}
```

EDIT: Here is my PrintWonders function

```
void PrintWonders(WonderT allWonders[], int count) {
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<count;i++) {
      cout << "Wonder " <<  i << endl;
      PrintWonder(allWonders[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: *Where* do you get this message ? Which line of code?

Comment: very likely solved with `PrintWonders(&wonders[players.GetPick()])`

Comment: @Stephan Lechner: Would be unusual, considering that they already use references to pass around individual objects.

Comment: Could you please post your `PrintWonders`-function?

Comment: The name `PrintWonders()` sounds like it expects an array as the argument, not a single `WonderT`.

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add the function signature of `PrintWonders`?

Comment: I added the Print Wonders function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PrintWonders()` (note the plural) wants an array of `WonderT` objects. It will loop through the array passing each object to `PrintWonder()` (note the singular).

Your code fails because you are picking a single random object from the array and passing it to `PrintWonders()` (plural) when you should be passing it to `PrintWonder()` (singular) instead:

```
void WonderSelect(Player& players, int wonderCount, WonderT wonders[]) {
    players.SetPick(rand() % wonderCount);
    // PrintWonders(wonders[players.GetPick()]); // <-- ERROR!
    PrintWonder(wonders[players.GetPick()]);     // <-- OK! 
    return;
}
```

If you want to call `PrintWonders()` (plural) with a single object as input, call it like this instead:

```
void WonderSelect(Player& players, int wonderCount, WonderT wonders[]) {
    players.SetPick(rand() % wonderCount);
    PrintWonders(&wonders[players.GetPick()], 1); // <-- OK!
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hey Remy, just wanted to say thank you! You solved my problem.